# Why is $Students and $Mentors accessible in ProjectsHolder.ss?

Tags: orm, silverstripe

In the tutorial listed below, Why is $Students and $Mentors accessible in ProjectsHolder.ss?

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/tutorials/dataobject_relationship_management/

```
<% include SideBar %>
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <h1>$Title</h1>
        <div class="content">
            $Content
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Project</th>
                        <th>Students</th>
                        <th>Mentors</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <% loop $Children %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
                        </td>    
                        <td>
                            <% loop $Students %>                                
                                $Name ($University)<% if $Last !=1 %>,<% end_if %>
                            <% end_loop %>
                        </td>    
                        <td>
                            <% loop $Mentors %>
                                $Name<% if $Last !=1 %>,<% end_if %>
                            <% end_loop %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end_loop %>
                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ProjectsHolder.ss` template loops through children `Project` pages with the following loop code:

```
<% loop $Children %>
    ...
<% end_loop %>
```

Inside that loop the code is in the scope of each one of those `Project` pages so it calls variables and functions on that `Project`.

As `Project` has a `Mentors` and a `Students` relationship these can be called within that loop.